# Why is the const overload of std::string::data still restricted in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

`std::basic_string::data` has a requirement under [its specification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/string.accessors).

> **[string.accessors]** (emphasis mine)
>
> ```
> const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
> const charT* data() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1 *Returns*: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0, size()]`.
>
> 2 *Complexity*: Constant time.
>
> 3 *Requires*: **The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array**.

This made sense in C++03 for `c_str` because it need not have returned a pointer to the actual string buffer, and for `data` because COW was a possible implementation strategy. Even if the buffer wasn't really const, modifying `data` would have interfered with the invariants of COW.

But since C++11 COW is disallowed, `c_str` and `data` return the same pointer, and it's to the very buffer `operator[]` would allow to modify. Why then is modifying the pointer via `const_cast<CharT*>(s.data())` still explicitly undefined behavior? Is there a practical reason?

Comment: "*Is there a practical reason?*" You mean, besides the fact that casting away `const` is considered *such* a bad idea that C++ created a cast specifically for doing so and explicitly disallowed all other (non-C-style) casts from doing it?

Comment: Um, because the object is `const`? The non-const version of `data()` allows modification of the contents. `operator[]` also doesn't allow modifying a `const` object.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I thought of that and tagged C++14 deliberately. There wan't a const overload then. And I'm not talking about a const `std::string`, but a non-const one. It will still be the same overload called for it, after all. It makes sense not to modify a const string, but for a non-const one...

Comment: @NicolBolas - Yes, I mean besides the boogieman we scare the uninitiated with. `const_cast` is still in, and not disallowed completely because it still has uses. Let's not get sidetracked, please.

Comment: Oh, your question is why didn't the standard add a non-const version sooner? <shrug>

Comment: @PeteBecker - No, that's a moot question. It's more  "given we all know this is most probably, definitely okay to modify, why not still?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm not talking about a const `std::string`, but a non-const one.

And that right there is why that statement exists (and continues to exist even in C++17, when a non-`const` `data` was added). Because `data` *doesn't know that*.

In a small-string optimized `string` implementation, the `string` object itself stores an array of characters. If that `string` object is declared `const`, then so too are its subobjects. [Modifying objects declared as `const` is UB](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.type.cv#4).

By contrast, `vector::data` has no such statement, because a `const vector` *always* heap-allocates its array. So while the array is logically `const` from the outside, it is technically well-defined (but you really, *really* shouldn't) to `const_cast` the return value from a `const` `vector::data`, because you're modifying an object that was not created as `const`.

If `basic_string::data` had no such statement, an SSO-based implementation would be impossible, because it would be *legal* to modify the elements of a `const string`, just like it's legal to modify the elements of a `const vector`. But it can't be legal to modify it, because it might be a `const` object whose data is stored internally.

Comment: Hmm, haven't considered SSO. Sounds very plausible.

Comment: _”Modifying objects declared as `const` is UB”_: in case other readers (like myself) wants a reference for this, see [\[dcl.type.cv\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.cv#4).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, thanks but I feel like this still doesn't answer the question.  For example, `&mystring[0]` is perfectly valid for obtaining a `char *` from a non-const string. Furthermore, for `const std::vector`, `data` returns a const pointer -- why doesn't `std::string` follow the same design? non-const `string` and `const string` are different types, so I don't see why they need to both return `const`.